# Is the differential of an absolute continuous curve on a manifold measurable

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, absolute-continuity

I am working with an absolute continuous curve $c:[a,b]\rightarrow M$ on a smooth manifold $M$. The manifold is equipped with a metric $d$ and the curve is absolute continuous with respect to $d$.

For $M=R^n$ equipped with the euclidean metric it is well known that the derivative $c':[a,b]\rightarrow R^n$ is measurable.

I am wondering if I can prove that $\dot{c}:[a,b]\rightarrow TM$ is measurable. Besides, how would I define measurability on $TM$.

Comment: is there anything special about the metric $d$?

Comment: no, but I found that measurability is a local property and therefore we can just set $M=R^n$

Comment: But that does not tell you a lot, unless (e.g.) your $d$ is equivalent to the standard metric on $\mathbb R^n$ in some local coordinates.

Comment: but I can always find coordinates for that this is true for example the exponential map, right?

Comment: @Mathsfreak: when you write "a metric $d$", do you mean a Riemannian metric? Your choice of notation suggests to most readers that you only mean a metric in the sense of metric spaces.

Comment: I just meant a metric. That means that I have to assume that this metric is equivalent to a Riemannian Distancefunktion